# Simple Custom ListView for Android Application?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am a history teacher with minimal coding experience attempting to create a "presidential fact" application for my class. I've watched/read through multiple tutorials, but I cannot seem to successfully create a simple custom listview in which I can edit text size and text color.

This is honestly all I need. A listview that actually allows me to customize it. I don't need it to do anything else but display text in a list.

I have a feeling the code is blatantly easy, but I'm at a total loss and I would like to have the application finished for my students by the end of the week.

Any straightforward tutorial links or code would be extremely appreciated. Thank you so much!

EDIT: I do know how to create items and populate a regular listview. The only trouble i am having is the ability to edit the text appearance. Thanks again!

Comment: When you say edit the text appearance, you mean editting it on the fly while running the app via e.g. an EditText in the ListView or do you just don't know how to set styles and fonts to the TextViews in your ListView?

Comment: Just style-wise. I don't need to edit on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement abstract [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) class. For example:

```
public class FeedAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<FeedItem> items;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    FeedAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FeedItem> list, int bgColor){
        items = list;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }   

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public FeedItem getItem(int index) {
        return items.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }   

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row;

        if (null == convertView) {
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.romanblack_feed_item, null);
        } else {
            row = convertView;
        }

        TextView title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.romanblack_rss_title);
        TextView description = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.romanblack_rss_description);
        TextView pubdate = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.romanblack_rss_pubdate);

        String titleString = items.get(position).getTitle();
        title.setText(titleString);

        String descString = items.get(position).getAnounce(70);
        description.setText(descString);

        pubdate.setText(items.get(position).getPubdate(""));

        return row;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an adapter for your listview and in that adapter inflate a custom layout. this layout will be used for each item of your listview. in that layout, you can do any changes you want.

edit : take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

Answer (score 0):

To style your views go to your values directory and edit or if not present create the styles.xml.
In there you can define standard values for view attributes, e.g.

```
<style name="TextStyleNormal" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/TextSizeNormal</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">2</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">2</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">2</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

then in your view xml definitions, just add that style to the desired views with

```
style="@style/TextStyleNormal"
```

Of course you can add any of these attributes directly to the view.